# How to profile and log slow methods in long lived Java application?

Tags: java

Is there any easy way to

- profile and write out to the file what methods are slow (>1sec)
- in a long lived Java application
- without any expensive overhead?

With all profilers I know (YourKit, NetBeans, etc), I always have to watch the graphical monitor whether or not a problem occurs.
Instead, I just want to get a hint to solve the problem by seeking log files when a problem occurs in customers side.

Answer (score 1):

I used [JAMon API](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/). It was powerfull and easy. But today there are a lot of options: [open-source profilers](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers)

Answer (score 0):

For maximum flexibility and control you can use aspects to time selected methods. Check out [spring-aop](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) for example. You will need to write the aspects yourself to time and log when necessary, but that should be quite straight forward.